# UTC Dates to Long conversion: Gson - Expected a long but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, json, mongodb, scala

I am trying to convert (decode?) a mongoDB BasicDBObject (called 'document') into a POJO, **but Gson is stumbling over the expiryTime, which is a UTC Date (2013-10-08T10:00:00.000Z).**

Here is the scala command:

```
gson.fromJson(document.toString(), classOf[MyObj])
```

I read that registering a TypeAdapter could be useful, which would look something like this:

```
val gson: Gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(classOf[org.joda.time.DateTime], new DateTimeTypeConverter).serializeNulls.create
```

**Any ideas on how to register the TypeAdapter for this date problem?**

The error:

```
Expected a long but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

POJOs:

```
public class MyObj { 
  private IdObj id; 
  private String uid;
  private Long expiryTime;
}

public class IdObj { 
  private String guid; 
  private Long timestamp;
}
```

JSON:

```
{  
   "_id":{  
      "guid":"guid",
      "timestamp":1381226400000
   },
   "uid":"uid",
   "expiryTime":{  
      "$date":"2013-10-08T10:00:00.000Z"
   }
}
```

I am using Scala 2.10.

Comment: `expiryTime` is a `Long`.

Comment: Yes, it's a Long in the POJO, but it's a UTC in the Json. Can I convert the UTC to a Long using Gson?

Comment: You'd need a specific `TypeAdapter` for only that field. That doesn't make much sense. You should use a `TypeAdapter` for `MyObjt` or use a JSON parsing library that has per field converters.

Comment: There isn't an existing TypeAdapter for converting UTC to Long?

Comment: There's no such thing as UTC here. What you have is a string which represents a very specific JSON object: `{"$date":"2013-10-08T10:00:00.000Z"}`. You're trying to convert that to a `Long` value. There is no such built in converter.

Comment: So, I set expiry time with: new java.util.Date(givenExpiryDateTime) Is there a way in Scala to convert this to a Long instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added two lines to update the java.util.Date date to a Long so that I could decode it. Here's the scala code:

```
def decodeDocument(document : BasicDBObject) : MyObj = {
  val currentTime : Date = Objects.firstNonNull[java.util.Date](document.get("expiryTime").asInstanceOf[java.util.Date], new Date())
  document.put("expiryTime", currentTime.getTime());
  gson.fromJson(document.toString, classOf[com.expedia.www.travelgraph.user.news.entities.NewsItem])
}
```